# How to put thumbnails to files in Win 10

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading from Win 7 my wifes long list of embroidery files downloads has lost all of there picture markers(thumbnails).
Any help .have tried Google suggestions but nothing seems to work
symeskeith3@gmail.com
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While folder opened,

1. Press Alt then T to open the tools menu
2. In the menu, you will have a menu item named as "Folder Options", click it, it will open folder options windows
3. Head to the 'View' tab in this window located at the top below the title bar
4. Now, in the Advance Settings box, you will find "Show hidden folders, files, and drives."
5. Once you check the box for this and apply the change, you should see a new file called "Thumbs.db" along with pictures, Delete "Thumbs.db" file
6. Set file explorer view to thumbnail mode
7. It will start regenerating thumbnails one by one, wait for Windows to recompile the thumbnail database and you will see thumbnails of pictures.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hit alt /t but nothing happened

Comment: Which OS you are using???

Comment: You can use this as alternative of step 1 to 4:

Comment: Windows 8.1 
Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, then select Search (or if you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then select Search).Type folder in the search box, then select Folder Options from the search results.Select the View tab.Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.

Comment: Windows 7 
Select the Start button, then select Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization.Select Folder Options, then select the View tab.Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.

Comment: Using Win 10 home

Comment: Windows 10 
In the search box on the taskbar, type folder, and then select Show hidden files and folders from the search results.Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.